# Why is it injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be group and $M$ be a set. Furthermore let $G_m$ be a the stabilizer of $m\in M$ and $Gm$ be the orbit of $m$ under the action.  Now my problem:

Let $\psi: G /G_m \to Gm$, $gG_m \mapsto g(m)$. I wanna show that $\psi$ is injective. Then the argument is given as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\psi(gG_m)=\psi(hG_m)& \Rightarrow g(m)=h(m)\\
& \Rightarrow (g^{-1}h)(m)=m\\
& \Rightarrow g^{-1}h \in G_m\\
& \Rightarrow gG_m =hG_m.
\end{align}$$
I just don't understand the last part, why we get $g^{-1}h \in G_m \Rightarrow gG_m =hG_m$?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: What is $G$? A group? An abelian group? What is $G_m$? What is $Gm$? What is $m$?

Comment: Sorry I corrected my question

Comment: $G_m$ is a subgroup. For **any** subgroup $K$, $gK=hK$ if and only if $h^{-1}g\in K$.

Comment: Your correction contained several errors.

Comment: Thank you for your correction.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the fact that is being used:

> If $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, then for $x,y\in G$ we have $xH=yH\iff x^{-1}y\in H$.

Here is a proof:

Suppose $xH=yH$. Then $y=y{\cdot}1\in yH=xH$ so we can write $y=xh$ for some $h\in H$. Then $x^{-1}y=h\in H$.

On the other hand suppose $x^{-1}y\in H$, say $x^{-1}y=h$. Notice then that $y=xh$ so given an element $yh'\in yH$ we have $yh'=(xh)h'=x(hh')\in xH$, which shows $yH\subseteq xH$. For the other inclusion notice $x=yh^{-1}$ so if $xh'\in xH$ then $xh'=(yh^{-1})h'=y(h^{-1}h')\in yH$.